# Non-repudiation isn't a part of cryptography?

Tags: terminology, non-repudiation

According to the "Handbook of Applied Cryptography" by Alfred J. Menezes, Paul C. van Oorschot, and Scott A. Vanstone (CRC Press, 1997; p.4):

> *Cryptography* is the study of mathematical techniques related to
> aspects of information security such as confidentiality, data
> integrity, entity authentication, and data origin authentication.

My questions are: Why doesn't non-repudiation appear in that definition? Is it less important? Isn't non-repudiation one of the aspects of information security?

Comment: The list of properties is introduced with "such as".. this suggests that the list is not intended to be exhaustive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is clearly a simplified definition, as cryptography encompasses a large number of ideas. It is likely for the same reason that they do not mention zero-knowledge proofs or proof-of-work systems, despite those very often falling squarely in the relm of cryptography.

Answer (score 3):

Mikero's comment about the passage you quoted is exactly right: *The list of properties is introduced with "such as".. this suggests that the list is not intended to be exhaustive.*

On page 3 of the book you quoted, the "Handbook of Applied Cryptography" by Alfred J. Menezes, Paul C. van Oorschot, and Scott A. Vanstone (CRC Press, 1997), Table 1.1 lists non-repudiation as a security objective.

[image]

Directly under the text you mentioned, it says that non-repudiation is a key objective, so here is the answer to your question.  The passage is show below (p.4):

> ### Cryptographic goals
>
> Of all the information security objectives listed in Table 1.1, the
> following four form a framework upon which the others will be derived:
> (1) privacy or confidentiality (§1.5,§1.8);(2) data integrity (§1.9);
> (3) authentication (§1.7); and (4) **non-repudiation** (§1.6).
>
> - 1. *Confidentiality* is a service used to keep the content of information from all but those authorized to have it. Secrecy is a
>      term synonymous with confidentiality and privacy. There are numerous
>      approaches to providing confidentiality, ranging from physical
>      protection to mathematical algorithms which render data
>      unintelligible.
> - 2. *Data integrity* is a service which addresses the unauthorized alteration of data. To assure data integrity, one must have the
>      ability to detect data manipulation by unauthorized parties. Data
>      manipulation includes such things as insertion, deletion, and
>      substitution.
> - 3. *Authentication* is a service related to identification. This function applies to both entities and information itself. Two parties
>      entering into a communication should identify each other. Information
>      delivered over a channel should be authenticated as to origin,date of
>      origin, data content, time sent, etc. For these reasons this aspect of
>      cryptography is usually subdivided into two major classes:entity
>      authentication and data origin authentication. Data origin
>      authentication implicitly provides data integrity(for if a message is
>      modified, the source has changed).
> - 4. ***Non-repudiation* is a service which prevents an entity from denying previous commitments or actions.** When disputes arise due to
>      an entity denying that certain actions were taken, a means to resolve
>      the situation is necessary. For example, one entity may authorize the
>      purchase of property by another entity and later deny such
>      authorization was granted. A procedure involving a trusted third party
>      is needed to resolve the dispute